# Subgroups of a finite $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G|=p^n$ for some $p$ prime and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I want to prove that if $k\le n$ then $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^k$.

I want to use induction on $k$. If $k=0$, then it is clear.

Let $n>k>0$ and suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $|H|=p^k$.

Now, the hint I was given is that $Z(G/H)$ is non-trivial, so it has an element of order $p$, say $z$. Somehow this has to give me a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^{k+1}$.

But I don't see why.

Is it related to correspondence theorem?

Thank you.

Comment: It should follow from one of the isomorphism theorems (there are 3 of these, though perhaps you know them by a different name- correspondence theorem might be appropriate for the one I am thinking of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\langle z \rangle$ is a subgroup of $G/H$ of order $p$. Thus, index of trivial group $\langle H \rangle$ in it is $p$. By correspondence theorem, inverse image of $\langle z \rangle$ by canonical epimorphism contains $H$ and index of $H$ in it is also $p$. Therefore, it is a group of order $p^{k+1}$. Also by correspondence theorem, it is normal in G because $\langle z \rangle$ is in center and therefore normal in $G/H$.

Comment: Thanks @Filip
I don't understand why $<z>$ is normal. I think that an abelian subgroup of a group may not be normal in the group.

Comment: @Sandor You are correct. It follows from $z$ being in center of $G/H$, and therefore for each $g \in G/H$, $g z^{i} g^{−1}=z^{i} \in \langle z \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks you very much @Filip

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find this informative.

[image]